# how to convert int to time in a pl/pgsql function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I would like to convert a given date and integer to a timestamp in a pl/pgsql function. i've never done anything with pl/pgsql before, so i'm somewhat at a loss.

Thanks to the answer by Pablo Santa Cruz, it got this far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION to_my_timestamp(mydate date, timeint integer) RETURNS timestamp AS $$
DECLARE
    myhours   integer := timeint / 10000;
    myminutes integer := timeint % 10000 / 100;
    myseconds integer := timeint % 100;
    timestring  text    := myhours || ':' || myminutes || ':' || myseconds;
BEGIN
    RETURN (mydate::text || ' ' || timestring)::timestamp;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select to_my_timestamp('2010-08-12',123456);
```

However, this doesn't seem to work for me yet. This is the error I get using pgadmin3 on Ubuntu:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 9: $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
        ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at end of input
SQL state: 42601
Character: 377
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your return value to:

```
RETURN (mydate::text || ' ' || timestring)::timestamp;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! but unfortunately, this doesn't work:

ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"

Comment: That should be mydate::text - two colons

Comment: @Magnus, @andrash: Yah! Sorry 'bout that type. Just fixed the answer. Try it. It should work.

Comment: hey Pablo, thanks. However, still no luck :( see my edited question above for error message.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `END;`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION to_my_timestamp(mydate date, timeint integer) RETURNS timestamp AS $$
DECLARE
    myhours   integer := timeint / 10000;
    myminutes integer := timeint % 10000 / 100;
    myseconds integer := timeint % 100;
    timestring  text    := myhours || ':' || myminutes || ':' || myseconds;
BEGIN
    RETURN (mydate::text || ' ' || timestring)::timestamp;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```